# Advice on editing NSStrings

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsstring, editing

For an app that I am currently making I need to break up a string into characters and then convert each of those characters into a number. One way I thought of doing this was by using the following code;

```
//Get string length
int stringLength = [myString length];

//Create new variable for "While" loop
int count = stringLength;

//Start "While" loop

while (count != 0) {

    //What I want her is for the NSString to be ("letter%i",count) but I don't know how to do this 
    letter1 = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,stringLenght-count)];

    //each letter = 1 so it will move down one letter at a time  
    count--

}
```

and then I would have something like;

```
if (string1 == @"a") {

    number1 = 5;

}



if (string2 == @"a") {

        number2 = 5;

    }
```

..........

Would I be able to read the new strings that I create from outside the while loop? Any suggestions would be very helpful. Also any way to do this another way would also be helpful too.

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan

Comment: I want the numbers to be in separate variables so that I can then convert them back into  letters, but with a different value and then add them all together back into a long string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your intentions, but I'll try and guess. What you want to do is iterate over the string, character-by-character, and analyse each character and store your conversion into an *array*.

```
// Get length of string
NSUInteger len = [myString length];

// allocate number buffer
NSUInteger *numbers = calloc(len, sizeof(NSUInteger));

// loop through the string's characters and assign to the number array.
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    unichar thisChar = [myString characterAtIndex:i];

    if (thisChar == 'A')
        numbers[i] = 5;
    else if (thisChar == 'C')
        numbers[i] = 10;
}

// do what you want with the numbers array, and then free it.
free(numbers)
```

Also, consider using a look-up table to convert a character to a number (if there are a large number of character-to-number conversions).

And just one last thing, you can't compare strings using `==`, because that will test for pointer equality, not for string equality. When you compare strings, you should use:

```
if ([someString isEqualToString:anotherString])
    // ... and so on ...
```

Comment: Thanks! One quick question; If number == 3 does that mean numbers[i] would be "numbers3"?.

Comment: Don't worry I have worked that one out! It does mean  that if number == 3 does that mean numbers[i] would be "numbers3". Thanks again!